# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0 (java selenium)

Tags: java, selenium, indexing

I'm trying to write a bot for instagram on selenium with java. I watched it from youtube and I wrote same code in video. But when I want try to open first posted image on a cummon instagram page I get this error.Can you help me why I getting this error? What it could be?

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App app = new App();
        app.loginWith("******","*****");
        app.navigateProfile("*****");
        app.clickFirstPost();
    }
}

public class App {

    WebDriver driver;
    String BASE_URL = "https://www.instagram.com/";
    By userLocator = new By.ByCssSelector("input[name='username']");
    By passLocator = new By.ByCssSelector("input[name='password']");
    By loginBtnLocator = new By.ByCssSelector("button[type='submit']");
    By instaLocator = By.className("_ab6-");
    By profileNameLocator = By.className("_aada");
    By postImageLocator = By.className("_aagw");

    public App(){
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get(BASE_URL);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    public  void loginWith(String userName, String password){
        waitFor(userLocator);
        driver.findElement(userLocator).sendKeys(userName);
        driver.findElement(passLocator).sendKeys(password);
        driver.findElement(loginBtnLocator).click();

    }

    public void navigateProfile(String profileName){
        waitFor(instaLocator);
        driver.navigate().to(BASE_URL.concat(profileName));
    }

    public void clickFirstPost(){
        waitFor(profileNameLocator);
        driver.findElements(postImageLocator).get(0).click(); // this code ave the error.
    }
    private void waitFor(By Locator){
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,15);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(Locator));
    }
}
```

Comment: It means you are trying to access the first element of a list that has no elements. Your search using the `postImageLocator` returned 0 results.

Comment: I searched on the internet but could not find or did not understand. For example I try to open page app.navigateProfile("nasa.turkiye"); there is 134 posts and I am trying to click first post. When I inspect and look for class name there is 24 same class name in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using same class in "wait" and "findElements". I don't know the cause or solution of the problem. But while the page is loading, I think findElements changes the number of index somehow. So I'm tried to find the first image directly with "wait" so that if there is a class that I want to click than findElements can find it too. Here is code.

```
//By profileNameLocator = By.className("_aada");
By postImageLocator = By.className("_aagw"); //just used same class for wait and findElements

   public void clickFirstPost(){
    waitFor(postImageLocator);
    driver.findElements(postImageLocator).get(0).click();

}
```

Comment: Yeah, you have to wait for visibility of the specified elements (in this case, elements from postImageLocator)

Your previous code only waited for profileNameLocator